# readHTMLTable does not recognize URL

Tags: r, xml

Okay guys, I have, what I'm sure, is an entry-level problem. Still, I cannot explain it. Here's my code and its error:

```
> sample1 = readHTMLTable(http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm, which = 16)
Error: unexpected '/' in "sample1 = readHTMLTable(http:/"
```

It's having a problem with the second front-slash? Not only does every URL have two front-slashes, but I've poured through countless examples of this function, both on this site and others, and they've all formatted this code in this way. So, what am I doing wrong?

Additionally, I've tried it without the back-slashes:

```
> sample1 = readHTMLTable(www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm, which = 16)
Error: unexpected symbol in "sample1 = readHTMLTable(www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm"
```

Here, I'm not even sure which symbol it's talking about.

Please explain.

Comment: You need to pass the URL as a quoted string: `readHTMLTable("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm", which = 16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to place your url in quotes (""). The following does return the table from your specified url:

```
sample1 = readHTMLTable("www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609150buf.htm")
```

As you probably know, the "which=" parameter is used to select which of the tables in that page you would like to retrieve. However my own attempts show that only 1 and 2 work. Could you tell me which table you are attempted to read into R? If this method doesn't end up working you can also attempt to read in the entirety of the webpage and parse out the table in question.

Hope this helps get things started!